# Extract encrypted rar archive without showing password

Tags: cmd, passwords, archive, unrar

i got an idea to make something like keychain with keys, which will contain possible passwords to extract my password protected archives. So passwords will stay hidden, but user will still able to extract archive without knowing password.

Problem is if i send password via parameter it is shown in command line parameters.

```
set mypass=12345
unrar.exe x test.rar -p%mypass%
```

i tried also send pass via echo but it doesnt seems to work

```
@echo off
@echo 12345 | unrar.exe x test.rar -p
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Isn't there a unrar.dll? I'd guess you'd have more control when you use that instead of an exe.

Comment: If you don't want anyone to read this then don't echo it! I don't see why you need to show a console. Use CREATE_NO_WINDOW when you call CreateProcess.

Comment: yes i checked this library, but wirar/unrar is more efective, library contains only basic fuctions for extraction, but winrar/unrar does also thing like store date and time with NTFS precision for extracted files, atributes etc, i search easiest solution

Comment: @David echo is off, but as i said parameters are show in command line paramers

Comment: I assumed you are using CreateProcess to create the unrar process since this is a programming Q&A site. But are you just typing this at the command prompt. I'm struggling for context. You tagged this delphi. Where is the delphi? Should we remove that tag?

Comment: i din't write delphi code yet, first i made tests to make sure how are command parameters dispayed.

Comment: As far as I know unrar.dll has same exctaction capabilities as unrar.exe does.

Comment: Check my edited answer below for example of using @echo off appraoch

Comment: You can't hide the password from a determined user.

Comment: @SilverWarrior echo is really not problem i could completely hide whole console window, but again if you press ctrl+shift+esc and look what parameters are shown near unrar.exe :(

Comment: when i use `unrar.exe x test.rar -p`   unrar will ask Enter password (will not be echoed): Reenter password: , thats why i tried pipe password from command A to command B, if this would work password would be hidden

Comment: We've told you multiple times that the password is provided in plain text form when passed as a command line argument. You've told us that is not acceptable, so surely you can reject that option and move on.

Answer (score 0):

Using of @echo off is the correct approach.

Do note that when you call

```
@echo something
```

that "something" is always shown even when you disabled the echo using @echo off.

Also I agree with Uli Gerhardt about the use of unrar.dll instead as this will give you even better control over the extracting process.

EDIT: If you put this code into batch file (*.bat) you will see that the commands won't be shown.

```
@echo off
set mypass=12345
notepad %mypass%
```

Same should apply when sending commands from your application.

EDIT2: Do you know that you can even find already made Delphi component which alows you to make use of unrar.dll?

Check at bottom of this page: http://www.rarlab.com/rar_add.htm

Answer (score 0):

The unrar executable does not provide a mechanism to securely accept the archive password. It is accepted in plain text form. There's no getting away from that and you should stop trying to do so.

Use the rar DLL interface instead which gives a slightly increased level of obfuscation. Of course, a moderately determined hacker could inspect the parameters that are being passed. Or inspect the file that is being extracted.